# Retrieving files from a document library using REST with a filter on a field

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, filter

I have a standard document library with one added field StudyId (string). I can't figure out how to retrieve files using a filter on that field.

I retrieve files as following:

`http://test-site/_api/web/lists/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/tmgt/StudyDocuments')/Files`

if I add a filter `?$filter=StudyId eq 123456` I get an error that StudyId field doesn't exist.

For file items fields are returned as properties, so I guess filtering is different, but I can't find out the proper way

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs since filter expression could **not** be applied for `File Collection` resource. From another hand, `StudyId` field is a property of `List Item` resource and not a `File`.

Having said that, you could utilize the following query to return File with `StudyId` set to `123456`:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('StudyDocuments')/items?$select=File&$expand=File&$filter=StudyId eq 123456
```

> It is assumed that `StudyDocuments` is a Documents library title.

Answer (score 1):

Files endpoint doesn't support filtering. Hence you should use CAML query along with REST endpoint

Url -

```
http://test-site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('StudyDocuments')/getitems
```

Body -

```
{
    'query' : {
        '__metadata' : { 'type' : 'SP.CamlQuery' },
        'ViewXml' : '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="StudyId"/><Value Type="Integer">123456</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>',
        'FolderServerRelativeUrl' : '/tmgt/StudyDocuments'
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I do it in a GET request (i.e. put the query in the url somehow) or do I need to do a POST?

Comment: It should be POST. Check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119505/combine-rest-query-getitems-action-with-odata-filter-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Libraries in SharePoint are a type of list. So, to query the library you use the same approach as querying a list.

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/fp142385.aspx

Query the list (library):

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('StudyDocuments')/items?$filter=...
```

For each item returned, get the file properties

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('StudyDocuments')/items/getbyid(###)/file
```

One of the properties returned is ServerRelativeUrl