# Convert CAML queries to OData Filters

Tags: rest, caml-query, odata

Is it possible to convert complex CAML query to OData filters so that I can use them in REST APIs? Some CAML queries have nested condition and multiple values to be passed in IN operator. Also, sometimes, these CAML queries will have to be dynamically generated. How can we convert these queries to OData filters?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your CAML query to this endpoint:

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists(listid)/getItems(query)
```

For low level details, refer [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/119648/43584)